# How can i access the subnode in Jtree

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtree

anyone help me i have Jtree and Subnode i want to click sub node and display one window form in java am using netbeans.

Comment: For better help sooner, consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using a tree selection listener. Look at [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) tutorial. In particular, [Responding to Node Selection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#select) section describes how to implement a basic selection listener.